# What is the optimal way to encode a tag to use in algolia?

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I have an article page that lists the tags related to that article.  When the user clicks on the tag it brings them to the Algolia search results page.  This is a Wordpress website.  Some of my tags happen to contain ampersands in them like "Spades & Shovels", for example.

What I've noticed is that when I urlencode this term it does not display the search term properly in the search box when I send it via a query string.

I've tried this and thought this was the secret sauce, but it doesn't always work.

```
$tag_name = json_encode(urlencode(html_entity_decode($tag->name)));
```

What would be the best way to encode a tag name so that when I pass it via a query string to the search results page it handles it properly?

I've done more testing and I am noticing some odd things on my search results page.  If I come to the search page with the searchbox field empty, but pass a post_id (I'm dynamically loading the tags associated with a post in the filter section), I can see "Spades & Shovels" listed there and it has a count of "65" next to it.

If I type "Spades & Shovels" into the searchbox, I see that number quickly drop down to 10 in the sidebar.

When I pass the tag in the query string no matter how I encode it, it doesn't seem to work.  I mean I see the words Spades & Shovel in the search box, but I don't get any results.  Its very strange, but probably something simple I'm hoping to fix.  I need to be able to pass & in a query string to my search results page, but I have not found the proper formula for sending an ampersand in the url for this to work.

It does seem like the value I am passing through in the query string is not an exact match to the actual tag name.

I have tried all of these possibilities and different combinations:

```
$clean_tag = json_encode(urlencode(html_entity_decode($tag->name)));

$clean_tag = htmlspecialchars_decode($clean_tag);

$clean_tag = html_entity_decode($clean_tag);

$clean_tag = urlencode($clean_tag);

$clean_tag = htmlentities($clean_tag);

$clean_tag = html_entity_decode($clean_tag);

$clean_tag = json_encode($clean_tag);
```

None of these seem to do the trick.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you explain more about why you need to url encode your tag name?
Also, could you share the custom code that is displaying the filters based on the current post ID?
I kinda understand what is not working and what you are trying to achieving, but I miss context here and there to actually give you a working example.
Could you narrow down the problem in a way that I can offer you a concrete solution? Please do share as much code and usage context as possible.

Comment: Sure, I'll update my question. I do think I have a solution from team algolia. But basically the problem is when the tag contains an ampersand in it's name. I'm sending the tag name in a query string. Therefore, I need to encode the tag to make it safe to send via the query string. There seems to be a problem in algolia with ampersands. We have to do some extra work to handle this. So anyway, if I don't encode the tag then it will think the & is the start of a new parameter in the query string.

Comment: I see, please do share the answer you got from the Algolia support regarding the & symbol.

Comment: A couple of weeks ago, Algolia told me that there was a bug with the & and then sometime last week they told me that they fixed it.